# Will a fragment be destroyed if setRetainInstance(true) is not called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following Advanced android development training by Google. Here is the [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-fragments/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#2). I came across this: [Added a static fragment in xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cu5v.png)

And on rotating the device, the selected radio button's state is retained as shown here:[landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDgOZ.png)

How is the fragment's state retained without using setRetainInstance(true)? Is the fragment not supposed to be destroyed along with the activity's onDestroy() method? If it is retained without explicitly calling setRetainInstance(true), what's the point of using the method? I'm confused with these two concepts. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the fragment's state retained without using setRetainInstance(true)?

Obvious user-mutable state of widgets is usually put into the saved instance state `Bundle` automatically. This includes things like the text in an `EditText` widget and the checked state of `CompoundButton` implementations, such as a `RadioButton`.

> Is the fragment not supposed to be destroyed along with the activity's onDestroy() method?

Yes.

> If it is retained without explicitly calling setRetainInstance(true), what's the point of using the method?

In modern Android app development, you would not use it, preferring to use the `ViewModel` system instead. It, under the covers, uses `setRetainInstance(true)`.

More generally, the point of retaining a fragment is for retaining state *other* than the obviously user-mutable state of widgets. For example, you might have some properties referencing business objects (e.g., an invoice, a customer) that you wanted to hold onto across the configuration change.

Comment: @G.Neeraja: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant "obvious", not "obviously" -- I have corrected my answer. Basically, if the user can change it by directly interacting with the widget, *probably* it is saved in the instance state `Bundle`. That's not always the case, such as the scroll position of a `ListView`, but it is good baseline rule.

Comment: I was about to ask a doubt regarding the quoted text. But I clicked enter without writing my doubt. That was not to mention the grammar. After thinking for a while my doubt was cleared. So, I deleted the comment. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: But in the example I quoted in the question, even the text view is retained though it's not user mutable. How is that possible without retaining the state of the fragment?

Comment: @G.Neeraja: If the `TextView` text is in the layout, your new fragment gets a fresh inflated layout, so it would get the text that way. If the `TextView` text was set by code, and you are [using `setFreezesText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText(boolean)), then the text will be saved in the instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: The text "Like" and "Thanks" is set through code. But is not lost. usingsetfreezesText() method is also not used in the code..

Comment: @G.Neeraja: Put a breakpoint in `onCheckedChanged()`. Since the text is being set in response to a `RadioButton` click, when the fragment is destroyed and recreated, and the saved instance state is applied, that listener may be called again.

Comment: Yeah.. Got it! Thank you